# Get current connection protocol in SQL 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, database-connection

I'm currently using SQL 2000 (it's a vendor server - don't ask...), and I'm wondering if there's a way to detect the connection protocol of connected clients. For SQL 2005+, I use:

```
select net_transport from sys.dm_exec_connections 
where session_id = @@spid
```

But SQL2000 lacks this dynamic view. Anybody know the equivalent function on SQL2000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT net_library FROM sysprocesses WHERE spid = @@SPID
```

You can also sys.sysprocesses in SQL Server 2005/2008. It may be deprecated but there is [no equivalent in after SQL 2000 for functionality, says MS Connect 144515](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=144515)